# Task Async confusion

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have been asked to convert a WCF service call from synchronous to async, but the call seems to still be running synchronously. What am I doing wrong?

**This is my service contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICredentialReplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the store database with credential data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credentials">the credential data to update</param>
    [OperationContract]
    Task ReplicateDataAsync(CredentialDataList credentials);
```

**This is my implementation**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Copy the credential data to the stores
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credentials">The credential data to copy</param>
    public async Task ReplicateDataAsync(CredentialDataList credentials)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateData(credentials));
        await task;  
    }
```

I have generated the proxy classes with the "generate asynchronous operations" flag set in the client, and I call the service with the following code (service call is right at the end)

```
 foreach (var store in storedic)
            {
                // call the replication service for that store                    
                CredentialDataList credentialData = new CredentialDataList();
                List<CredentialData> credentialList = new List<CredentialData>();

                foreach (var payroll in store)
                {
                    CredentialData cred = this.ExtractCredentialData(data, pinData, payroll);
                    credentialList.Add(cred);                       
                }

                credentialData.CredentialList = credentialList.ToArray();
                credentialData.PermissionList = permDataList;
                credentialData.PermissionTypeList = permTypeDataList;   

                // then call the service
                this._client.ReplicateData(credentialData);     
            }
```

I had thought that stepping through this loop in the debugger should come back straight away, but instead it waits for the service call to complete before it returns. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be, that you have to call **ReplicateDataAsync()** instead of ReplicateData?

Comment: Could be I guess maybe I have been getting confused by the examples I have been looking at

Comment: I think you used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613678/Task-based-Asynchronous-Operation-in-WCF) example?

Comment: If you're using .Net 4.5 you can also replace `Task.Factory.StartNew` by `Task.Run()`. [See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) for more info / differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you're using the **synchronous** version of your client API instead of the **asynchronous** version:

```
this._client.ReplicateData(credentialData);
```

Instead of using the [async over sync anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), i'd suggest that instead use the *synchronous* version of the API.

Use WCF to [generate a task based operation](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=983) which you can await:

[image: Wcf settings]

```
var replicatedData =  await _client.ReplicateDataAsync();
```

Comment: What's the benefit of changing the framework's thread to a thread from a pool?

Comment: @UserControl - Didn't see this was WCF. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you are quite right with the "task based" option

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your old synchronous method in your implementation.

```
this._client.ReplicateData(credentialData);
```

You would call the async version like so:

```
await this._client.ReplicateDataAsync(credentialData);
```

Your method signature would also need the async modifier if it doesn't already.

Comment: I don't see a ReplicateDataAsync method on client, I only see ReplicateData/ BeginReplicateData / EndReplicateData

Comment: I presumed the ReplicateDataAsync method was added to the same class that ReplicateData is in? Regardless, you need to call the ReplicateDataAsync method instead of the older synchronous one you're replacing.

Comment: OK, I have deleted and re-added the reference, looks like updating it was not enough. I can now see the Async method

Answer (score 0):

### Fix the code

You have to call the WCF service method in a different way:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this._client.ReplicateData(credentialData));
```

### Or use the magic

Or another possibility would be to keep the same code of the service and just configure the client to call the servie asynchronously. This configuration can be done by changing the properties of the service refference in the visual studio. After the configuration you can simply use the method called `<MethodName>Async()`. No changes needed on the service side.

[Edit]

How your code should look like after:

**Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICredentialReplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the store database with credential data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credentials">the credential data to update</param>
    [OperationContract]
    void ReplicateData(CredentialDataList credentials);
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy the credential data to the stores
/// </summary>
/// <param name="credentials">The credential data to copy</param>
public void ReplicateData(CredentialDataList credentials)
{
    UpdateData(credentials); 
}
```

**Consume of the service:**

```
this._client.ReplicateDataAsync(credentialData);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think the root of my problem is that I don't see the Async version of the method. Which property should I change in the service reference? I already have "generate asynchronous operations" ticked

Comment: Try to rewrite **Task ReplicateDataAsync()** to void ReplicateData() and update the data in your method implementation normally without asynchronous. After that you delete your Service Reference and recreate it and check again the "generate asynchronous operations". After that you should be able to consume the service asynchronosuly via **ReplicateDataAsync()**.

Comment: Do you gain anything by creating a task and then immediately await that task? Tasks are still foreign to me.

Comment: @DougDawson No this is a fault by my side. Only if the Task has a return value you can get the value like this: `var value = await task;`